# Django why request.method=='GET' when refreshing the page

Tags: django, get, refresh

I want to have some search boxes on my page and my related codes are like below, my problem is why when i refresh the page the if clause: " if request.method=='GET':"  executes without i click on any button ?

```
def allstocks_view(request):
 if request.method=='GET':
     question_set =Stocks.objects.all().filter(confirm=_('approved') )
     name=request.GET.get('namesearch')
     number=request.GET.get('numbersearch')
     brand=request.GET.get('brandsearch')

     if name is not None :
          question_set = question_set.filter(name__icontains = name)
     if number is not None :
          question_set = question_set.filter(number__icontains = number)
     if request.GET.get("brandsearch"):
          question_set = question_set.filter(brand__icontains = brand)
     print(">>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>")
     print(question_set)
```

template :

```
<form  method="get">
{% csrf_token %}
<div class="">
<label for="namesearch">Name</label>
<input type="text" name="namesearch" >
<label for="numbersearch"> Number</label>
<input type="text" name="numbersearch" >
<label for="brandsearch"> Brand</label>
<input type="text" name="brandsearch" >
<label for="brandsearch"> City</label>
<input type="text" name="citysearch" >
<input type="submit" name="search" value="Search">
</div>
</form>
```

Comment: Why wouldn't it be a GET? What else do you think it would be?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A refresh of a page is a `GET` request unless your last action was a `POST` request so that is going to execute every time. What you could do is make the form a post and handle in a `request.method == 'POST'` block. Another option if you wanted to continute with `GET` would be have your view take an optional parameter such as `search=None` and set up your urls accordingly. Then in your view you could check for if `search` exists instead of `request.method == 'GET'`.